# diamond diagram with large objects

Tags: xy-pic

I am trying the following:

```
\[
\xymatrix@C-70pt{
{}& *+[r]{I\times_E I=\{(p,L_i,L_j)\ |\ p\in L_i, p\in L_j\}}
\ar[dl]\ar[dr] & {}\\
I\ar[rd] &{}&*+[r]{I=\{(p,L_i)\ |\ p\in L_i\}}\ar[dl]\\
{}&E&{}
}
\]
```

but I want the diagonal arrows to form a perfect diamond (I want the equation after the equality sign to extend to the right on its own, not affecting the diagram), while now the two arrows on the right half of the diagram are too large.

Or in other words, I wish I could draw the diagram with just `I` and `I\times I`, and then to whatever diagram I get, just to add the `I=...` or `I\times I = ...` stuff, without affecting the diagram.

Any fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go for masking the width of the unwanted pieces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example
\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\[
\xymatrix{
  & I\times_E I\makebox[0pt][l]{${}=\{(p,L_i,L_j)\mid p\in L_i, p\in L_j\}$} \ar[dl] \ar[dr] \\
  I\ar[rd] && I\makebox[0pt][l]{${}=\{(p,L_i)\mid p\in L_i\}$} \ar[dl]\\
  & E
}\hspace{6em}% adjust to suit
\]
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

You would have to guess the column width anyway, instead of the final spacing.

[image]

Comment: @XymatrixUser Maybe there's a more Xy-pic savvy workaround for removing the unwanted width; but “if it works, don't fix it”.